# How can i Edit Category Description File

Tags: magento-1.9, category-description

I want to  some changes in  **category Description**  how can I edit this file?

its calling from.
**app/design/frontend/default/spazeapparel/template/catalog/category/view.php**

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
<div class="category-description std">
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But i am unable to find particular  description file .

Comment: you can description from adminpanel,so  why you want to change programetically ?

Comment: You can update category description from Admin panel > Catalog > Manage Categories > Description field.

Comment: @thanks For reply i want to  add dome **div ** and jquery Functions

Comment: Then add it in view.phtml you got the file @Grace

Comment: @ Gopal Patel . I am using theme there already Define some **div**  So I want to change that **Div name**  But still  i am unable to fine that file

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the files directly?

If so you need to activate the handy dandy template path hints.

Just go into your magento admin.

Go to System > Configuration > Current Configuration Scope > Select Default Store View (or what you default named your store)

When it has activated the scope of the Default Store go to Advanced > Developer > Debug > Template Path Hints > Yes

Then go to System > Cache Management and Disable all the Cache.

Now go to the front end and view the page you want to have changes on.

You will see this:
[image]

Take note of the paths by taking a screenshot or listing down the paths.

Go back to the settings and do the Default Store go to Advanced > Developer > Debug > Template Path Hints > (Set to) No

You will then have the reload the page at the frontend without the path hints.

Use the paths to find where you need to copy the file from or edit the theme file.

---

And when you are done editing and everything is working fine.

Go back to the cache and enable them again.

Comment: my issue solved that **class** or **div** coming from custom js Files